# How many time an azure blob is accessed?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

the Metrics can show total transaction for all blob in a storage account, but I cannot filter by container or blob.

Thanks.
Lidong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the Metrics can show total transaction for all blob in a storage account, but I cannot filter by container or blob.

We could find the detail logs in the Azure storage **$logs** container. About how to enable and access log data please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/enabling-storage-logging-and-accessing-log-data#FindingyourStorageLogginglogdata).

After that we could use [Microsoft Message Analyzer to analyze log data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-e2e-troubleshooting). 
You could filter the data what you wanted